# Can I still use a UASP enabled SATA-to-USB 3.0 adapter when my laptop doesn't UASP?

Tags: usb, usb-3, uasp

I' m looking to buy a SATA-to-USB adapter for an external HDD. On Amazon I came across this adapter from [UGREEN (SB 3.0 IDE SATA Hard Drive Adapter for 2.5/3.5 Inch SATA HDD SSD with External DC 12V 2A Power Supply)](https://www.amazon.nl/B019SW4Z42/) that has UASP enabled for even better transfer speeds. I've used `Device Manager` on Windows 11 to check if UASP is enabled on my laptop by looking under `Storage controllers` and `Universal Serial Bus Controllers`, but unfortunately it is not.

My question is:

#### Can I still use a UASP enabled SATA-to-USB 3.0 adapter when my laptop doesn't UASP?

Comment: You don't really mention, the specifications for the HDD, but the device likely work. You just won't get any benefit from the UASP capabible device.  UASP has been around since before 2011.  I wouldn't trust your determination that your device doesn't support UASP

Comment: @Ramhound I [posted a fuller answer](https://superuser.com/a/1774026/167207) but the “worst” that would happen is UASP will not be enabled and the standard 5Gbps USB 3.0 connection happens. Nothing to complain about to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can can definitely use a UASP enabled SATA-to-USB 3.0 adapter but it will not connect with UASP and there will be no UASP speed boost as a result.

USAP is an extension to USB connection that will be enabled if it exists, but safely ignored if not. As this page on the [StarTech website](https://www.startech.com/en-us/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-uasp) explains:

> UASP stands for USB Attached SCSI Protocol. It allows for faster read/write data speeds to and from storage devices.
>
> Compared to traditional USB 3.0 BOT, UASP performs up to 70% faster read speeds and 40% faster write speeds at peak performance.

As well as this; bold emphasis is mine:

> Having a supported Operating System and hard drive enclosure/dock are not the only requirements for taking advantage of UASP. **Your USB controller on your computer also needs to support UASP.**

So if your OS and system do not support UASP, UASP will not be enabled. FWIW, most of the external enclosures and multi-connection cables (like the one you linked to) will support UASP if your system and OS support it. So it’s not really a unique feature of this UGREEN device.

That said, USB 3.0 is 5Gbps so honestly you already have decent speed for a connection like this.